# Can we use terraform to backup azure file share to another azure file share

Tags: azure, file, azure-blob-storage, storage

I got backup folder sync issues with azcppy and can I use terraform for backup between two az file shares? Daily say 100 TB backup I want to do without any network glitch or skipping files between cross region

Large backup solution within azurcloud only from one az file share to another az file share is needed

Comment: can you please share the configuration you tried so far @Himanshuk

Comment: If Azcopy does not meet your expectations, you can use ADF instead. Terraform has limited options for this task. You need a solution that supports reliable data transfer capabilities, such as Azure Data Factory or scripted solutions using Azure CLI or PowerShell with retries and error handling.

Comment: I have tried all but I found new azcopy version 10.23 have issue that while azcopy sync it will not sync destination files and old files remains there, so need alternative mechanism instead azcopy utility